# Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am getting an error while deploying my Angular app containing Firebase Cloud Functions to Firebase. I've no clue why am I getting this even after "deploy complete" message. Please help.

Below are the last few lines of CLI.

```
=== Deploying to 'havok-test'...

i  deploying hosting

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/havok-test/overview
Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined
```

Comment: File a bug report on the Firebase CLI GitHub.  Be sure you're on the latest version.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson It might be worth posting that as an answer. While you may not be able to help with a proper solution here, I think directing them to support or the Github repo **is** the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as Community wiki, as per comments in the question. Feel free to modify it as your will

The best approach for this case is to File a bug report for the Firebase CLI, on its official GitHub. The bug can be reported using this following link here: [Firebase CLI Repository](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Since they are the developers for the mentioned feature, they should be able to better handle this case.

Thanks @DougStevenson and @FrankvanPuffelen for the information!